# Compile error: method or data member not found when trying to run RegEx code

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I found the following StackOverflow question.
[How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

I added "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" to my references in the VBA interface, and typed in `12abc` in cell `A1` as in the example. I then did Insert -> Module and copied the following code to the code box:

```vb
Function simpleCellRegex(Myrange As Range) As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strPattern = "^[0-9]{1,3}"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value
        strReplace = ""

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.test(strInput) Then
            simpleCellRegex = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        Else
            simpleCellRegex = "Not matched"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

When I type `=simpleCellRegex(A1)` in cell `B1` I get the error

> Compile error: method or data member not found

In the debugger the first line of the code is highlighted.

Someone in a comment to an answer mentioned that an error might occur if the code is in `ThisWorkbook`, but mine is in `Modules`.

Comment: You don't have Regular Expressions 1.0 also turned on do you?

Comment: No repro following those exact steps.

Comment: @Warcupine Huh, apparently it was turned on. And now everything works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `Late Binding` by calling the `CreateObject` Function. It avoids possible bugs associated with mistakenly referencing unneeded libraries or cross referencing them. See below:

```
Public Function simpleCellRegex(ByRef Myrange As Range) As String

    Dim regEx As Object
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strPattern = "^[0-9]{1,3}"

    'late binding
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value
        strReplace = ""

        With regEx

            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.test(strInput) Then
            simpleCellRegex = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        Else
            simpleCellRegex = "Not matched"
        End If

    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be useful for any future endeavors in VBA. Oddly (or maybe not, I don't know), when I turn on Regular Expressions 1.0 after having them turned off (so both 5.5 and 1.0 are working) the code executes just fine. But if I first select 1.0 and then turn on 5.5 I get the error.

Comment: @Antsushi You can set the priority order of references, the first clicked has a higher priority so any conflicting references now default to 1.0. You can change this with the arrows to the right of the list.

Comment: @Antsushi ^^^^ what @Warcupine said. `CreateObject` in my opinion is still the better way to go in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the reference was added to the module and workbook where you are trying to execute the function

the module must be selected in order to add the reference to that specific module:
[image]

here it shows that my `Module1` has the reference "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"

and if said reference is unchecked, you'll get this error: `Compile error: method or data member not found`

this is the result I got:

[image]